# Left excluding join in sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

I have two tables, where one table has the ID of the other. 1:1 relation.
So something like

```
EventFeedback
    somePrimaryKey
    userEventID
UserEvent
    userEventID
```

Sequalize has the relation defined with

```
models.UserEvent.hasOne(models.EventFeedback, { foreignKey: 'userEventID' });
```

I need all entries in `UserEvent` that do not have an entry in `EventFeedback`, which is an exclusionary join.
Stealing images from [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/kb/database/visual_sql_joins.aspx) because they have nice individual images: [image: left excluding join]

They even give example code!

```
SELECT <select_list> 
FROM Table_A A
LEFT JOIN Table_B B
ON A.Key = B.Key
WHERE B.Key IS NULL
```

How do I do this in sequelize?
Do I just need to do a left join and process it manually?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to eager load `EventFeedback` when querying `UserEvent` and add proper `where` clause. You also need to define that `EventFeedback` is not required in the result so the query will generate `LEFT JOIN` instead `INNER JOIN`

```js
UserEvent.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: EventFeedback,
        required: false, // do not generate INNER JOIN
        attributes: [] // do not return any columns of the EventFeedback table
    }],
    where: sequelize.where(
        sequelize.col('EventFeedback.userEventID'),
        'IS',
        null
    )
}).then(userEvents => {
    // user events...
});
```

In the code above the `sequelize` is an instance of Sequelize with model defined in it. You can also refer to the documentation of [`sequelize.where()`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/#whereattr-comparator-logic-sequelizewhere) and [`sequelize.col()`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/#colcol-sequelizecol) methods.

Answer (score 0):

By default SEQUALIZE always use INNER JOIN. 
It's very easy to make it LEFT JOIN.
Just add the...

```
required: false
```

along with the code.
Follow the sample query code.

```
 UserModel.findAll({
        attributes: {
            exclude: ['role_id', 'username', 'password', 'otp', 'active']
        },
        where: {
            active: 1,
            role_id: 2
        },
        include: [{
            model: StateModel,
            attributes: ['id', 'short_name'],
            as: 'state_details',
            where: {
                active: 1
            },
            required: false
        }]
    }).then(List => {
        console.log(List);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);            
 });
```

Comment: adding `required:false` isn't enough.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can also use the **on** clause in the associated table:

```
UserEvent.findAll({
    include: [
      {
        model: EventFeedback,
        as: 'feedback',
        on: { user_event_id: null },
      },
    ]
  });
```

This will do a LEFT OUTER JOIN event_feedback ON  user_event_id IS NULL.