# Sequelize: Exclude LEFT JOIN where column value is null

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I have two tables: "tags"; and "tags_meta".

I have no problem performing joins on these two tables, I have a situation where I need to find rows in "tags" that don't have a corresponding row in the "tags_meta" table, where "tag_id" is the foreign key, and "tag_type_id" is — as the name suggests — the *type* of tag.

```
Tags.getTagsAsUnclassified = function(params) {

  const paginate = ({ page, pageNumber }) => {
    const offset = (parseInt(page) > 0) ? parseInt(page) : 0
    const limit = parseInt(pageNumber)
    return {
      offset,
      limit
    }
  }

  const Op = Sequelize.Op

  return this.findAndCountAll({
    attributes: [
     ['tag_id', 'tagID'],
      'user_id',
      'tag'
    ],
    include: [{
      model: TagsMeta,
      as: 'TagsMeta',
      where: {
        tag_type_id: null
      },
      required: false
    }],
    where: {
      user_id: params.userID
    },
    group: [
      [[sequelize.col("tags.tag_id"), "ASC"]]
    ],
    order: [
      ['tag', 'ASC']
    ],
    ...paginate({ ...params })
  })
  .then(result => {
    return {
      count: result.count.length,
      rows: result.rows
    }
  })

}
```

While this returns *some* correct rows, it's a bit of a mixed bag.

I've tried [an answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43125842/630530), but that hasn't worked.

I leave it to the experts!